# App not displaying properly with Safari - Nginx configuration problem?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

I am deploying 10 shiny apps using Shinyproxy inside docker-compose. I have set up a Nginx reverse proxy on my server for information. The apps are loading perfectly fine on Google Chrome but not when using Safari. I inspected the element and saw two different types of errors:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
- Refused to execute 'url' as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.

Can anyone explain to me why are these errors happening with Safari and not Google Chrome? Is there anything I could do?

The 10 apps are available at https://www.derivativesacademy.com/derivatives-pricer/

You can click on any of them with Safari Browser to see what I mean and inspect the element.

From my research, the second error is related to Nginx configuration. I have tried tons of things in the conf file hoping it will get better with no success so far.

For information, I have created a new conf file that is inserted inside nginx.conf to make sure I did not do anything stupid with the initial configuration file. I share with you the content of the created conf file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name XXX;

    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam.pem
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/snippets/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/chain.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

To give further information, please see the screenshots when inspecting the element on Safari. None of these elements are red in Chrome.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help appreciated,

Maxime

Answer (score 1):

I updated to the last version of Shinyproxy (2.4.2) and it solves the problem!

Can't believe I spent so much time for such a solution but if it could spare some time to anyone using older version of Shinyproxy (I was on 2.3.0 for info).